# Why is siblings not working here?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

In the item tamplate I have this

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Textbox runat="server" id="txt">foo 1</asp:Textbox>
    <asp:label runat="server" id="lab" cssclass="l">foo 2</asp:label>

</ItemTemplate>
```

My jquery is like this

```
 $("input:text").blur(function () {
      $(this).parent().siblings().css("background", "yellow");
 }
```

That script works, but if I add in the class for sibilings it does not work.

```
 $(this).parent().siblings(".l").css("background", "yellow");
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you please add the actual HTML output to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to change the background of the  rendered control, you may be able to do it as such:

```
$("input:text").blur(function () {
      $(this).siblings(".1").css("background", "yellow");
 }
```